# Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio

hello I use fabric for the crash but I'm having problems with `Android` below 5

error :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.adp.picassoapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.adp.picassoapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /data/datalib]]
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5184)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4733)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4666)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1439)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.adp.picassoapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.adp.picassoapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /data/datalib]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5169)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4733) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4666) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1439) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:966) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:733) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enable multidex
for devices with Android API prior to 21,
Include the multidex library :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

and extend `MultiDexApplication` in your Application class

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Add `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultConfig{}` app level gradle

Answer (score 1):

Add multidex library into your app build Gradle and enabled multiDex true in defaultConfig

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Did it   ,  then ?

Comment: Again, it fails

Comment: @alimodares, Please provide the code how did u implement exactly?

Comment: Error before opening the program's front page.  And because of the fabric library

Comment: Include this code in your Application class: onCreate{Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());  ACRA.init(this);} and then try

Comment: what  ACRA.init (this);  ?